# Kubernetes Using Proxy without ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, reverse-proxy

My issue is that I have a web server running on port 80. I want to use nginx proxy (not the ingress) bto redirect the connection. I want to use link wwww.example.com. How should I tell nginx to proxy the connection on wwww.example.com  (which is a different app). I tried using service with load balancer but it changes the hostname ( to some aws link) I need it to be exactly wwww.example.com.

Comment: Have you tried `NodePort`? Create `A` Record points to cluster machine, and access proxy via `www.example.com:<NodePort>`?...(But it is not a efficient solution)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly, you may just use `return` directive in your nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.some-service.com;
    return 301 $scheme://wwww.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you need something more complex check [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) doc or [this](https://bjornjohansen.no/nginx-redirect)